# Normal Sylow Subgroups of Solvable Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

If $G$ is square free such that $|G|=p_1\cdots p_n$, where $p_n>p_{n-1}>\cdots$. Then we can use the N/C Theorem, along with some induction, to show that the Sylow $p_n$-subgroup of $G$, $P_n$, is normal in $G$.

Suppose $G$ isn't square free, and let's assume $G$ is solvable.  Suppose $p_k$ is the largest prime divisor of $G$ with exponent $1$.  Could we necessarily say $P_k\trianglelefteq G$?

Comment: What about $A_4$?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is no, as noted in a comment by Steve D. For example, consider $G = A_4$, which has order $2^2 \cdot 3$ but does not have a normal Sylow $3$-subgroup.

In fact a finite solvable group does not need to have any normal Sylow subgroups, consider for example $G = S_4$.

But the answer is yes for some classes of solvable groups. For example besides groups of squarefree order, more generally the property you ask about holds for [supersolvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersolvable_group) finite groups.

That is, if $G$ is a finite supersolvable group and $p$ is the largest prime divisor of $|G|$, then $G$ has a normal $p$-Sylow.

Comment: thank you!  For your last comment, do you have a proof of that statement you can cite or state?  Thank you again!

Comment: You can see Theorem 10.5.3 in Marshall Hall's group theory book. Main points: 1) you can find a normal series where the quotients are cyclic of prime order 2) a group of order $pq$ with $p \leq q$ has a normal subgroup of order $q$.

Answer (score 3):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$One of the possible generalizations of the $A_{4}$ example is the following.

Let $p$ be **any** odd prime.

Let $k$ be the order of $2$ modulo $p$, so that $p \mid 2^{k} - 1$.

Let $N$ be an elementary abelian group of order $2^{k}$.
Then $N$ has an automorphism $\alpha$ of order $p$. This is because $N$ can be regarded as the additive group of the field $F$ with $2^{k}$ element. The multiplicative group of $F$ is cyclic of order $2^{k} - 1$, generated by an element $b$, say. Multiplication by $b$ yields an automorphism $\beta$ of $N$ of order $2^{k} - 1$, and then one can take
$$
\alpha = \beta^{(2^{k} - 1)/p}.
$$

Let $P = \Span{a}$ be a cyclic group of order $p$

The homomorphism $P \to \Aut(N)$ determined by $a \mapsto \alpha$ yields a semidirect product
$$
G = N \rtimes P
$$
which is soluble, and whose order $p \cdot 2^{k}$ is not squarefree as $k > 1$.

Since $N$ is normal in $G$, but $G$ is non-abelian, we have that $P$ is not normal in $G$.

The case of $A_{4}$ occurs when $p = 3$, and $k = 2$.

Comment: Thank you!  As testaccount pointed out, what I say above is true if $G$ were supersolvable.  Besides this example, would there be other instances (that you can think of) where $G$ being only solvable would not be sufficient?  If so, perhaps there is a way to generalize those cases...

Comment: Well, this example shows that given any odd prime $p$, there is a finite soluble group $G$ such that $p$ is the largest prime divisor of the order of $G$ with exponent $1$, and a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is not normal in $G$. What kind of further examples do you have in mind?